# Error 204 when doing an objectPost in RestKit 0.20.3

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit-0.20

Please help.  I am very new to RestKit and have been struggling for days to get a fairly straight forward POST successfully executed using RestKit .20.3.  I follow all the various samples and instructions and used part of Alexander Edge's tutorial and the RestKit GitHub samples and documentation to no avail.  Can someone take a quick glance at my code and give me some tips on what i can do to perform a successful POST using RestKit .20.3? I suspect that my last line of code is faulty because, my postObject is "nil" but, I am just not sure.  Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

BTW: The error i receive in my debug logs is "Expected status code in (400-499), got 204"

```
- (void)setupRestKitTutorial{
NSLog(@"setupRestKitTutorial - Start");

RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL]];
//[manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

//[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" value:@"inquiryData"];
//[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" value:@"inquiryData"];


//Set up Request Header
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"clientAccount" value:@"6"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"docType" value:@"T"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"userId" value:@"uid01"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"class" value:headerClass];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"clientCode" value:@"02"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"requestType" value:@"submit"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"token" value:@"f3a6a4dc1c8f77d79a1a1f6a5d439933"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"documentNum" value:@"439299827"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

//End setup Request Header


NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];

[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                                                    keyPath:@"error"
                                                                                statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[errorDescriptor]];


NSDictionary *parentObjectMapping = @{
                                      @"inquiryStatus" : @"inquiryStatus",
                                      @"entityNo" : @"entityNo",
                                      @"docType" : @"docType",
                                      @"docNumber" : @"docNumber",
                                      @"mvNumber" : @"mvNumber",
                                      @"totalAmount" : @"totalAmount"
                                      };

RKEntityMapping *ticketParentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([TicketParent class]) inManagedObjectStore:manager.managedObjectStore];
ticketParentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"entityNo" ];
[ticketParentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"name" : @"name"
 }];
[ticketParentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:parentObjectMapping];


/**
 Complete Core Data stack initialization
 */

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TicketParent.sqlite"];

NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil  withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

[manager postObject:nil path:@"http://www.mytesturl.com/jsonservices" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"We object mapped the response with the following result: %@", result);
} failure:nil];
```

}

Here is my updated code.  I made all the suggest mods and now I am getting the following error:  got 500" UserInfo=0x95c7bd0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]] 
Any ideas on a fix?

```
- (void)setupRestKitTutorial{
NSLog(@"setupRestKitTutorial - Start");

RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL]];
[manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];


[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"clientAccount" : @"clientAccount",
 @"docType" : @"docType",
 @"userId" : @"userId",
 @"class1" : @"class1",
 @"clientCode" : @"clientCode",
 @"requestType" : @"requestType",
 @"token" : @"token",
 @"documentNum" : @"documentNum"}];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping objectClass:[RequestInquiry class]                                       rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];


[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" value:@"inquiryData"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" value:@"inquiryData"];


//Set up Request Header
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"clientAccount" value:@"6"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"docType" value:@"T"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"userId" value:@"uid01"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"class1" value:headerClass];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"clientCode" value:@"02"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"requestType" value:@"submit"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"token" value:@"f3a6a4dc1c8f77d79a1a1f6a5d439933"];
[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"documentNum" value:@"439299827"];
//[[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"contenttype" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

//End setup Request Header


NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];

[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                                                keyPath:@"error"
                                                                                //statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
                                                                                statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[errorDescriptor]];


NSDictionary *parentObjectMapping = @{
                                      @"inquiryStatus" : @"inquiryStatus",
                                      @"entityNo" : @"entityNo",
                                      @"docType" : @"docType",
                                      @"docNumber" : @"docNumber",
                                      @"mvNumber" : @"mvNumber",
                                      @"totalAmount" : @"totalAmount"
                                      };


RKEntityMapping *ticketParentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([TicketParent class]) inManagedObjectStore:manager.managedObjectStore];
ticketParentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"entityNo" ];
[ticketParentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"mvType" : @"mvType"
 }];
[ticketParentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:parentObjectMapping];


/**
 Complete Core Data stack initialization
 */

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TicketParent.sqlite"];

NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil  withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

// Request Object with json paramaters
RequestInquiry *requestInquiry = [[RequestInquiry alloc] init];
requestInquiry.docType = @"T";
requestInquiry.documentNum = @"439299827";
requestInquiry.clientAccount = @"6";
requestInquiry.clientCode = @"02";
requestInquiry.token = @"f3a6a4dc1c8f77d79a1a1f6a5d439933";
requestInquiry.requestType = @"submit";
requestInquiry.userId = @"uid01";
requestInquiry.class1 = @"class com.rest.client.JsonRequest";

[manager postObject:requestInquiry path:@"/RestIVR/restservices/ticketservices/jinquiry" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *ticketParentMapping)
 {
     RKLogError(@"%@",ticketParentMapping);
 }
            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     RKLogError(@"%@",error);
 }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post object cannot be `nil`, the whole point is that you are trying to post that object. The 204 response is basically confirmation that the server received your request but had no work to do.

The path you're using should not be the full URL. You configure the manager with `managerWithBaseURL` so the path should be the additional part on the `getDataURL`.

You get `"Expected status code in (400-499), got 204"` because you have configured a good generic error handling response descriptor (applies to anything because the path pattern is `nil`. You should also be specifying a response descriptor for the success case. You create `ticketParentMapping` but never actually use it for anything...

Comment: Makes sense to me.  I thought that since I was setting up my request header at the top of my code via the HTTPClient setting.  So, I've added a new class called "RequestInquiry" that contains all the properties that my REST service is expecting as part of the request and then added that object to the objectPost parameter but, i still get a 204 error code. I also took your recommendation and fixed the URL and still no luck.  ticketParentMapping is used later in my code.  I really appreciate the quick and informative response. Thanks again.  I'll keep researching and post the response.

Comment: You created a mapping for `RequestInquiry` and associated request descriptor?

Comment: Using the example in the RKObjectManager reference guide, I created a .h and .m class file called RequestInquiry and created the parameters as properties in my class. Then I create an object (requestInquiry) in the code based on RequestInquiry, set the properties to the values my REST service is expecting and then pass the object via postObject:requestInquiry.  Also based on the comment below by @tekstop I created a RequestDescriptor with mappings.  I can repost my code if it will help.

Comment: Had a bit of break thru and got my request descriptor straightened out.  However, I am now receiving the error below.  Any suggestions on a resolution. Error: NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7757650>}

Comment: Update the code in your question. Looks like the server is returning the wrong type. Did you set an Accept header?

Comment: Took your hint and added [manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON]; and that fixed my issue.  However, now I am getting "JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type " but, I think that has more to do with my ResponseObject.  Thanks again for your useful input.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above POST implies that the object you are passing will be serialized based on the RequestDescriptor to the URL you are pointing at.

nil will not work.
Also, you haven't setup a RequestDescriptor

Comment: I believe i have corrected the issue of using nil with the postObject and I also took your advice and created a RequestDescriptor (good call) but, still get the 204 error code.  Really appreciate your quick and helpful response.  If you can think of anything else I am doing wrong please let me know.

Comment: Problem solved.  After entering every header parameter that appeared in my log into WizTools, I found that the Accept parameter was being set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" through the use of manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];  Once i commented out that statement I started getting a 200 response code.